# click counting per user per link

Tags: php, counter

on my site, in member area after successful login by user, lecture playback is available.
lecture list is fetched through mysql database and displayed on page to logged in member.

lecture details shown contains lecture subject, lecturer, lecture date and recording link for lecture.

when member clicks recording link, i want to add this click record with lecture subject for that specific logged in member.

so I can see which member viewed which lectures in my admin panel..

how can i achieve it ?

What I think is - I have to use onclick event to href of recording link and then update mysql table with member id, member name, lecture name. I dn't knw whether this thinking is right or not ? and not getting how to figure it out..

Comment: Use a `WHERE` clause with a GET href and conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts you need to solve your problem: Counter and a way to detect that counter should be incremented.

The first part, the counter, is easy. Create a SQL table with three columns: user id (foreign key to user account), record id (foreign key to whatever you want to count) and a counter (integer). You may want to add last visit column (timestamp). Then you need a function to increment the counter. It is a simple INSERT/UPDATE query to increment the counter column and set current time to the last visit column (if desired). You may want to watch more parameters than *who* and *what*, for example *where* the link was clicked -- simply add additional columns with appropriate foreign keys (you may need table of URLs if you cannot determine a linked entity or page where the link was).

The second part, the click detection, depends on how your application is built. Google uses onmousedown which changes search result link to a counter which redirects to original URL. So when user hovers mouse on the link, a result url is visible, but when link is clicked, it changes to something else. Another, but similar, approach is to use XHR request to increment the counter and then send user to desired destination. Both approaches are about calling PHP script which increments the counter and sends redirect as a response (or a 'ok' in case of XHR way).

Alternative approach to the second part is to handle this on server completely. If you have a PHP script which sends record to client, simply insert increment call somewhere into the script. When user downloads the record, the counter will be incremented and then user receive the record.